# What exactly is "filtered" in archetype-metadata.xml

Tags: maven, velocity, maven-archetype

The [maven-documentation](https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/specification/archetype-metadata.html) is not very helpful:

> Filesets can be filtered, which means the selected files will be used as Velocity templates. They can be non-filtered, which means the selected files will be copied without modification.

So let's take the underneath code. I know that the selected files will be used as Velocity templates and therefore they can be manipulated.
How can I manipulate this fileset and how can I use Velocity templates?

```xml
<fileSets>
    <fileSet filtered="true" packaged="true">
      <directory>src/test/java</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>**/*.java</include>
      </includes>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>AllTest.java</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, if you set `filtered` to `true`, then the Velocity engine takes the files and does all the Velocity replacements, including replacing variables given in the `$` syntax and evaluating Velocity loops.

The variable values are the properties set in the POM.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was wondering if I could also include or exclude files while filtering.
But it looks like I have to do it the way it was suggested in this comment (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARCHETYPE-274?focusedCommentId=16602773&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-16602773)